# Monit: 2 checks, one action

Tags: monit

Is something like this possible with monit:

```
check process foo with bar
check process foo2 with bar2
  start program = "baz start"
  stop program = "baz stop"
```

Basically I'm looking for an "OR" condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly OR condition you asked for but take a look at `check process <name> matching <regex>` syntax.

```
CHECK PROCESS <unique name> MATCHING <regex>

<regex> is alternative process specification using pattern matching
to process name (command line) from process table instead of pidfile.
```

Example:

```
check process foo_foo2 matching "foo_name|foo2_name"
  start program = "baz start"
  stop program  = "baz stop"
```

Comment: Thanks, ideally I'd want to match the pidfile though, but "pidfile matching" doesn't seem to be valid.